# iOS contacts app that can print data from vCards

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, contacts, airprint

Is anyone aware of an iOS app that can sync with CardDav to get a contact list and can then print off a nicely formatted contact card?

Basically, I want to be able to print information for referrals for patients.  Contacts can work great for holding this information, but we can't print it from iPads

Comment: would this work for you https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-my-contacts/id580072606?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the contacts out is to use the [Workflow app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow-powerful-automation/id915249334?mt=8) as it can receive contacts from the Share Contact control and then parse the input.

If you want the address, just dump the entire contact to the printer. If you want to customize things, you can select specific fields or set variables / pass the data to a python script that runs in [Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista/id528579881?mt=8).

Comment: No no, way off base here.  I'll try to clarify, what we want is the ability to open up a contact on the ipad and print the contact information to a printer to give to someone.

Comment: @ajm_from_sea Workflow app prints directly from the Contacts app to any local AirPrint printer. I tested it and have the piece of paper with the address from that contact in my hand. The only thing I didn't address was vCards - that's up to you to get imported into the iPad contact app - but that's not usually difficult. What's off base here?